# Cohomological criterion for $G$-equivariant maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a surjective map from a fourmanifold $M$ to a surface $N$, with  connected fibers (each fiber is connected). Assume that $f$ admits a multiple section $s:N\rightarrow M$.

Suppose now that we are given a finite group $G$ acting freely on $M$ in such a way that the fiber class and the multiple section class in $H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ are invariant or multiplied by $-1$. Can we conclude that the map $f$ is $G$-equivariant and descends to $f':M/G\rightarrow N/G$ as topological spaces (as $G$ action may not be free on $N$)?

A point I am confused by is that the fiber class and the section class are preserved (invariant or multiplied by -1) as classes, not as cycles.

**Edit**
My question turns out to be non-sense in its original form above. So let me change my question. I am reading [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002080050125) by M. Gross and P.H.M. Wilson, where they study SYZ conjecture for certain CY3s. I now try to understand the proof of Theorem 2.1. where certain holomorphic map $f$ is claimed to be anti-holomorphic $C_2$-action equivariant. Here the assumption in my question is satisfied. I now understand the (anti-)holomorphicity of the map $f$ ($C_2$-action) is crucial. But it is not yet clear to me why $f$ is $C_2$-action equivariant.

Comment: Koopa -- what is the action of $G$ on $N$?

Comment: @algori We don't know whether or not the $G$-action descends to $N$. Rather that's exactly what I am asking; if $G$ preserves the fiber class and the multiple section class, can one conclude that $f$ preserves the fiber and thus the $G$-action on $M$ induces that of $N$? 

Comment: Koopa -- what do you mean by "$f$ preserves the fiber"?

Comment: .. if you meant to say that $G$ takes fibers to fibres, than this is certainly false, at least in this generality (at least when $G\neq\{e\}$): e.g., take a map $f:M\to N$ for which everything is fine and perturb it slightly to make sure the image of some fiber under some element of $G$ is not a fiber.

Comment: Existence of an invariant multisection does not help. In all cases you can take first arbitrary multisection and then take its average.

Comment: What is a "multiple section" or "multisection" of a surjective map? (My guess is it assigns to each point in the base a subset of the fibre, but then I have several guesses for what continuity means in this context.)

Comment: @Mark I don't say how good the map $f:M\rightarrow N$ is, but assume generic smoothness of $f$, then the map $f$ is fiber bundle over some open set $U$ in $N$. Then we first construct a local multi(ple)section as a collection of continuous (smooth etc) maps $s_i:U\rightarrow F$, where $F$ is the fiber. If these extends over $N\setminus U$, then they glue together to yield a multi(ple)section. That's my understanding. (This may be wrong as I don't have any reference at hand now). 

Comment: @algori You are right. My claim is not true in smooth categorr, and we need some rigidity. I edited my question, as I have a particular example in my mind. Thank you for your useful comments. 